# SQL: WHERE with variable?

Tags: mysql

I have a db with talbe inventory, rental for cars

Table car:

> ```
>     car_id | store_id
> -------------------------
>      1     |      1
>      2     |      1
>      3     |      2   
>     [..]   |     [..]
> ```
>
> where store_id can only be 1 or 2

Table history:

> ```
> rental_id |    return   |    rental   |   car_id 
> ----------------------------------------------------
>    1      | 2009.02.02  | 2009.01.12  |     5      
>    2      | 2002.05.24  | 2009.05.01  |     8
>    3      |    NULL     | 2016.07.04  |     236       
>   [..]    |    [..]     |    [..]     |    [..]
> ```

I have to return:
1. store_id
2. return "return_date"
3. number of car returned on 2009.11.23
4. number of car rented on the 2009.11.23

Where a car  on the  2009.11.23 is rented if:
rental <= 2009.11.23 AND(return > 2009.11.23 OR return IS NULL )

Consider that date format are fixed and work :D

This is my code:

> ```
> SELECT store_id, 
>       h.return "return_date" ,
>       COUNT (h.return) "cars returned"
>       SUM(CASE WHEN (h.rental < h.return 
>             AND (h.return > 2009.11.23 OR h.return IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "cars rented"
>
>
>       FROM history h JOIN car i ON h.car_id = car.car_id        
>
>       WHERE h.return = 2009.11.23
>
>       GROUP BY car.store_id
> ```

I builded the "cars returned" and "cars rented" on separated table first and both display the right result.
In only one SELECT i have the following problems:
**1.** the

> ```
>          WHERE h.return = 2009.11.23
> ```
>
> will make the "cars rented" always be 0 since
>                h.return > 2009.11.23

**2.**
i want to avoid writing

> ```
>       h.return > 2009.11.23
> ```

Is it possible to declare a variable x so i can set it to 2009.11.23 and the write something like

> ```
>    SUM(CASE WHEN h.return = x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "cars returned"
>    SUM(CASE WHEN (h.rental < h.return 
>             AND (h.return > x OR h.return IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "cars rented"
>        [...]
>
>         WHERE x = 2009.11.23
> ```

Comment: why do you have dates setup like that?

Comment: they are given so and i can't change that :(

Comment: for the query i have to use `2009.11.23` so i have done a                   `TO_CHAR(h.return, 'YYYY.MM.DD')` which is also given as tip

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would do that like so:

```
SET @x = '2009.11.23';

SELECT store_id, 
  h.return "return_date" ,
  COUNT (h.return) "cars returned"
  SUM(CASE WHEN (h.rental < h.return 
        AND (h.return > @x OR h.return IS NULL)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "cars rented"
  FROM history h JOIN car i ON h.car_id = car.car_id        
  WHERE h.return = @x
  GROUP BY car.store_id;
```

**Reference:** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: why do you have `%x` in a few places?

Comment: @imtheman  I have done as you said but get the                                                                             **"near "SET": syntax error:"**                                                                                                              I also tried to put                                                                                              `@X "return_date" ` but then i get                                                      **Error while preparing statement: could not bind parameter @X**